# How can we resolve a TypeError is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with NodeJS. I'm getting .   TypeError: chosenHandler is not a function...
at this line
"chosenHandler(data,function(statusCode,payload,contentType)"
When I added
"chosenHandler = trimmedPath.indexOf('public/') > -1 ? handlers.public : chosenHandler;"

I get the error. When i remove it, code is fine but can't access items in the public folder. Which can be done only by "public/". So can any one give me a rough idea how can i reaolve it or any work around. I'm tring to learn NodeJS, so only using NodeJS and nothing else(no external library).

```
    // Dependencies
    var http = require('http');
    var https = require('https');
    var url = require('url');
    var StringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;
    var config = require('./config');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var handlers = require('./handlers');
    var helpers = require('./helpers');
    var path = require('path');
    var util = require('util');
    var debug = util.debuglog('server');


    // Instantiate the server module object
    var server = {};

    // Instantiate the HTTP server
    server.httpServer = http.createServer(function(req,res){
      server.unifiedServer(req,res);
    });

    // Instantiate the HTTPS server
    server.httpsServerOptions = {
      'key': fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'/../https/key.pem')),
      'cert': fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'/../https/cert.pem'))
    };
    server.httpsServer = https.createServer(server.httpsServerOptions,function(req,res){
      server.unifiedServer(req,res);
    });

    server.unifiedServer = function(req,res){

      var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
      
      // Get the path
      var path = parsedUrl.pathname;
      var trimmedPath = path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '');
      
      // Get the query string as an object
      var queryStringObject = parsedUrl.query;
      
      // Get the HTTP method
      var method = req.method.toLowerCase();
      
      //Get the headers as an object
      var headers = req.headers;
      
      // Get the payload,if any
      var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf-8');
      var buffer = '';
      req.on('data', function(data) {
        buffer += decoder.write(data);
      });
      req.on('end', function() {
        buffer += decoder.end();
        
        // Check the router for a matching path for a handler. If one is not found, use the notFound handler instead.
        var chosenHandler = typeof(server.router[trimmedPath]) !== 'undefined' ? server.router[trimmedPath] : handlers.notFound;
        
        // If the request is within the public directory use the public handler
        chosenHandler = trimmedPath.indexOf('public/') > -1 ? handlers.public : chosenHandler;
        
        // Construct the data object to send to the handler
        var data = {
          'trimmedPath' : trimmedPath,
          'queryStringObject' : queryStringObject,
          'method' : method,
          'headers' : headers,
          'payload' : helpers.parseJsonToObject(buffer)
        };
        
        // Route the request to the handler specified in the router
   ''''//Getting Error in this line//''''
        chosenHandler(data,function(statusCode,payload,contentType) {
          
          // Determine the type of response (fallback to JSON)
          contentType = typeof(contentType) == 'string' ? contentType : 'json';
          // Use the status code returned from the handler, or set the default status code to 200
          statusCode = typeof(statusCode) == 'number' ? statusCode : 200;
          
          
          // Return the response parts that are Content-Type specific
          var payloadString = '';
          if (contentType == 'json') {
            // Return the response
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            // Use the payload returned from the handler, or set the default payload to an empty object
            payload = typeof(payload) == 'object'? payload : {};
            // Convert the payload to a string
            payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);
          }
          if (contentType == 'html') {
             // Return the response
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            payloadString = typeof(payload) == 'string' ? payload : '';
          }
          if (contentType == 'favicon') {
             // Return the response
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/x-icon');
            payloadString = typeof(payload) !== 'undefined' ? payload : '';
          }
          if (contentType == 'css') {
             // Return the response
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css');
            payloadString = typeof(payload) !== 'undefined' ? payload : '';
          }
          if (contentType == 'png') {
             // Return the response
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
            payloadString = typeof(payload) !== 'undefined' ? payload : '';
          }
          if (contentType == 'jpg') {
             // Return the response
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
            payloadString = typeof(payload) !== 'undefined' ? payload : '';
          }
          if (contentType == 'plain') {
             // Return the response
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            payloadString = typeof(payload) !== 'undefined' ? payload : '';
          }
          
          // Return the respose parts common to all content types
          res.writeHead(statusCode);
          res.end(payloadString);
          
          
          
          // If the response is 200, print green, otherwise print red
          if(statusCode == 200){
            debug('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m',method.toUpperCase()+' /'+trimmedPath+' '+statusCode);
          } else {
            debug('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m',method.toUpperCase()+' /'+trimmedPath+' '+statusCode);
          }
        });
        
      });
    };

    // Define the request router
    server.router = {
       '' : handlers.index,
       'ping' : handlers.ping,
       'api/users' : handlers.users,
       'api/tokens' : handlers.tokens,
       'api/checks' : handlers.checks,
       'favicon.ico' : handlers.favicon,
       'public' : handlers.public
    };

     
    server.init = function() {
        // Start the HTTP server
        server.httpServer.listen(config.httpPort,function(){
          console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m','The HTTP server is running on port '+config.httpPort);
        });

        // Start the HTTPS server
        server.httpsServer.listen(config.httpsPort,function(){
          console.log('\x1b[35m%s\x1b[0m','The HTTPS server is running on port '+config.httpsPort);
        });
    };

     module.exports = server;
```

Comment: If you want to learn NodeJS you might need to install an IDE that let you debug your code. Visual Studio Code is a good one and it's free. In your specific case "handlers.public" or "chosenHandler" variables do not contain a callable function but something else. So you might want to execute your code and put a breakpoint there to understand what you are doing. If this code is not yourse, I would suggest you to start learning from scratch and not from an existing code... To understand Javascript you need to understand functions, it's mostly based on them.

Comment: Thanks for help. I read about the typeError and it comes mainly due to the inapropriate incomeing parameters from the callback to it. So i checked it all, if the payload or any other are sending wrong type of data to the parameters.  It only shows when i add the above line i.e chosenHandler=trimmedPath.indexOf(...;